# Как сменить стиль кнопки?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть в фреймворке ссылка для добавления записи в закладки с помощью `ajax`.

PHP делает свое дело - все ок. В БД данные заносятся.

Остается решить, как без перезагрузки сменить стиль иконки кнопки?

```
<a class='btn btn-default ewRowLink btn-sm' title='Add in bookmark' 
href="#" onclick="return SubmitAction(event, {action: 'star', method: 'ajax', msg: 'Add in bookmark?', key: {id:68}});">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark'></i></a>
```

Сменить на такой стиль

```
<a class='btn btn-default ewRowLink btn-sm' title='Add in bookmark' 
href="#" onclick="return SubmitAction(event, {action: 'star', method: 'ajax', msg: 'Add in bookmark?', key: {id:68}});">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark gray'></i></a>
```

После перезагрузки стиль меняется.

Comment: Исправьте свой вопрос. Ваш код не виден.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сменить стиль, независимо от результата работы PHP-части:

```
onclick="$('i.glyphicon').addClass('gray'); return SubmitAction(event, {action: 'star', method: 'ajax', msg: 'Add in bookmark?', key: {id:68}});"
```

если добавление класса к элементу должно происходить по условию, то эту строчку нужно вызывать в функции, которая вызывается после/в конце работы `SubmitAction()`

Comment: Сработало, но сразу на все записи в таблице. Еще не уточнил, что у меня рядом есть еще несколько аналогичных кнопок с иконками - на них тоже наложился стиль

Comment: <a class="btn btn-default ewRowLink btn-sm" href="#" onclick="return SubmitAction(event, {action: 'star_envelope', method: 'ajax', msg: 'Envelope?', key: {id:68}});"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
    <a class='btn btn-default ewRowLink btn-sm' href="#" onclick="$('i.glyphicon').addClass('gray'); return SubmitAction(event, {action: 'star_remove', method: 'ajax', msg: 'Add to bookmark?', key: {id:68}});"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark'></i></a>

Comment: раз вы пошли таким путём, то разделяйте селекторы:
`$('i.glyphicon-envelope').addClass('gray');` на первую кнопку
 и
`$('i.glyphicon-bookmark').addClass('gray');` на вторую кнопку в приведённом коде